# Why do I have a .subversion folder hidden in my home folder on mac OS?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, homebrew, subversion

Why do I have a .subversion folder hidden in my home folder on mac OS? I don't remember installing subversion. Inside the .subversion folder is see the following:

```
my-iMac:.subversion my-imac$ ls
README.txt  auth        config      homebrew    servers
```

How do i figure out how this folder was installed? Once I do, how do I uninstall subversion and homebrew? Why is homebrew even on my mac? How do i uninstall the programs that originally installed these?

Comment: it is shipped with OS X  https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#osx

Comment: I thought subversion arrived by installing Xcode's Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a Time Machine backup and delete it? It’s a common code control tool and any number of packages could use it to manage the software changes in your home directory without even going into if it’s not actually subversion and instead malware.

You would figure out how it was created by looking at snapshots of backups and also using the `mdls` tool to examine all the date related metadata and origin of each file in that folder. The modification and creation dates of the files will clue you in to how recent the files are and help you see if it’s something currently running or perhaps just migrated in from a long time ago on an old computer.